# FilesDir on mocked context Is null

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, androidx

I am new to unit testing and currently using Mockito for my Kotlin android application.

I use Koin for dependency injection in my view model class. I have successfully mocked out the dependencies. I pass mockedContext to my viewModel class but when calling mockedContext.filesDir it returns null.

Am I missing something?

HomeViewModelClass

```
init {
    directoryManager.createDirectory()
}
```

DirectoryManager

```
class DirectoryManager(val context:Context){

    fun createDirectory(){
        val filePath: String = context.filesDir.absolutePath
    }
}
```

HomeViewModelTest

```
@Mock
private lateinit var mockedContext: Context
private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

@Before
fun setup() {
    homeViewModel = HomeViewModel(mockedContext)
}
```

Getting null for context.filesDir in DirectoryManager

Comment: Doesn't look like you defined any behaviour for the mock of `Context`.

Comment: If you do not want mocking Context. Search `Robolectric` or `Instrumented test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for me was to use mockedApplication instead!